# Export a mysql table to all excel versions dynamicly using php/javascript...is it possible?

Tags: php, mysql, export-to-excel, export-to-csv

```
<?php
 $database="picinfo";
$table="passed_searches";
mysql_connect("localhost","root","root");
mysql_select_db("picinfo");
$result=mysql_query("select * from $table");
$out = '';
$fields = mysql_list_fields('search_engine',$table);
$columns = mysql_num_fields($fields);
for ($i = 0; $i < $columns; $i++)
{
$l=mysql_field_name($fields, $i);
$out .= ' "' .$l. '" ,';
}
$out .="\n";
while ($l = mysql_fetch_array($result)) 
{
 for ($i = 0; $i < $columns; $i++)
 {
 $out .='  " ' .$l["$i"]. ' " ,';
 }
 $out .="\n";
}
$f = fopen ('export.csv','w');
fputs($f, $out);
fclose($f);
$filename = date("Y-m-d_H-i",time());
header('Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel;'); 
header("Content-type: application/x-msexcel");          
header( "Content-disposition: filename=".$filename.".csv");
readfile('export.csv');
?>
```

This code is exporting on of the table in my mysql database (phpmyadmin)..the problem is that this code is exporting the data only in excel 2010 when i tried this code to export to 2013 it doesnt work.I want to change my code or find a way to export to all vesrions of excel,or fit the data in each of them,or give an option to the user to choose.

For example if the button to excel isset then view other buttons e.g export to excel 2007,export to excel 2008,export to excel 2008,export to excel 2009....export to excel 2013.Please help,this is very importand for me...im doing this for my graduation,an its just a small part of all the things i have to do.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is just feeding an CSV to excel. If you want real excel files, try using PHPExcel.

Comment: "*all vesrions of excel*"?  What, [including Excel v1.0 for the Mac](http://miedl.net/wp-content/uploads/2007/05/excel_1.0.jpg)?

Comment: not in Mac, just in windows office

Answer (score 0):

This is a plugin that I have used in the past.

It has a lot of features but works ever time and is very reusable

http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/

Comment: Can you post a working example using phpexcel.php? i downloaded phpexcel.php but it doesnt work..and i think its under license,so i can use it in my project.

Comment: PHPExcel is under an LGPL license, which means that you can use it freely in pretty much any project whether private or commercial.... and explain what you mean by "doesn't work"... did you read the documentations, try the examples... did your code give you any errors

Answer (score 0):

All versions of Excel support CSV-Files.

If you export a CSV file use the corresponding MIME-type:

```
header('Content-Type: text/csv');
```

Only use **one** `header()` with `Content-Type`

Comment: It doesnt make any difference i take the same output(excel 2013).Im not getting the data in idividual cells...